# C - Macro of chain of parenthesis to single macro

Tags: c, macros

As subject said, I'm trying to implement such syntax ("macro magic"):
`MAKE(123)(456)` which produces macro like 'RESULT(123,456)'

```
// MAKE(123)(456)

#define COMMA ,
#define RESULT(A,B) ((A)+(B)) // Just for example. In fact, I want to concat arguments of two or more macros

#define LP (
#define RP )

#define MAKE(A) __MK1(A) __MK2

#define __MK1(A) RESULT LP A COMMA // I'm tried many combinationations.
#define __MK2(A) A RP
// RESULT(123, 456);
```

Is it possible to do such thing?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need that, if you don't mind me asking? Surely there is a better, macro-less, solution.

Comment: @2501 I'm trying to implement Extension methods in c++11, just for fun. Current macro and aode work fine, but it looks like 'MAKE_EXT_TEMPLATE(bool,is_set,T,......)', but 'MAKE_EXT_OF(T)(bool,is_set,.....)' looks nicer.
P.S. my friend asked exactly the same question.

Comment: @snipervld If you're programming in C++11, why are you asking about C? They're different languages.

Comment: I need c++11 in the real task, but now i want only to convert 'MAKE(A)(B)' to 'RESULT(A,B)'. Nothing else. I said, that I'm using c++11 in the real task, because @2501 asked me about purpose of these macros Macros are C thing, right?

Comment: Code like `MAKE(123)(456)` doesn't make sense in C or C++ so why would you want to write something like that? It does _not_ look nicer, it looks like complete gibberish. Don't try to re-invent the language, doing so is very bad practice...

Comment: My question: is it possible to do such thing? Combine two argument lists

Comment: You can only do it if the first parameter consists of one of a number of predefined strings of "identifier" characters (alphanumerics and underscores), and you'd need to define a macro for each of the possible values of the first parameter. I'm guessing you are looking for something more general than that, in which case the answer is that it is impossible.